# SnowSQL connection test fails with "No module named 'win32timezone'"

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowsql

I've just installed SnowSQL for Windows as per the instructions at https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/snowsql-install-config.html#installing-snowsql-on-microsoft-windows-using-the-installer

However, when I attempt to connect to Snowflake, it fails:

```
C:\>snowsql -a <account> -u <user> --authenticator externalbrowser -o log_level=DEBUG
No module named 'win32timezone'
If the error message is unclear, enable logging using -o log_level=DEBUG and see the log to find out the cause. Contact support for further help.
Goodbye!

C:\>snowsql -v
Version: 1.2.7
```

Any ideas appreciated

Comment: I'll just mention a pretty typical Windows solution here.  Reboot, reinstall, reboot.  See if that helps.  Doesn't look like it was installed correctly to me.

Comment: Hi, I reinstalled as per your suggestion, but I get exactly the same error, i.e.: "No module named 'win32timezone'"

Answer (score 0):

What version of windows are you using? How did you install?

> No module named 'win32timezone'

Per the official documentation [snowsql is a python application](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/snowsql.html). The error message above is a python error indicating it cannot find the aforementioned package. However, installing that package is not likely a fix as snowsql appears to ship with a version of python. Which makes a lot of sense, dealing with python dependencies is a nightmare.

I started a Windows 2016 host in AWS and installed snowsql 1.2.7 via the MSI. I was able to get to the [login screen without any problems](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dcwez.png).

I would completely remove snowsql, do a search for snowsql and delete any folders you find, then reinstall. If it's still not working I'd provide more information as requested above.

Answer (score 0):

This was acknowledged as a defect by Snowflake, and they will fix it in a newer version. The workaround is to install v 1.2.5, and invoke this version from the command line

```
snowflake <options> -v 1.2.5
```